# files in usb drive are not hidden but not showing

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, usb-flash-drive, file-recovery

I copied some hidden files from another computer and when I open them in my computer I noticed that a folder is missing. But my computer shows that folder's space is taken. When I set to show hidden files and folders it shows the other hidden files and folders but not that folder. I ran windows defender scan and it scans the mentioned folder's files (the number of files scanned is equal to the all files with the missing folder's files). Is there a way that I can get my files back?

Comment: Have you also enabled display of hidden system files?

Comment: yes. but still doesn't show the folder.

Comment: Have you copied the files to your computer's disk (or SSD), or are you talking about a "thumb drive" (a.k.a. "flash drive")?  If the latter, can you try to read it on another computer?  Ideally running Linux?  In either case, can you boot your computer from a Linux live CD?

Comment: Yes this is about the thumb drive. Did not tried linux or any other os yet but tried on other windows computer. I'll try linux and let you know. thank you for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Is your USB drive infected by some kind of malware? Your problem seems to be a sign of a piece of malware hiding your files automatically and maliciously. The best way to check that is to try listing the files in Command Prompt (suppose the drive letter is E):

```
E:
CD \
DIR /A \
attrib /L
```

Do you see files with Hidden attributes? Or do you see some kind of YourFolderName.exe files around? If that's the case, you should delete it, and better have your whole drive virus-scanned first.

(Not intended to self-advertise, but I wrote the [usb_vaccine](https://github.com/Explorer09/usb_vaccine) script when I have many such problems with some other friends' USB drives.)